# how to integrate offline dictionary with pdf reader in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dictionary, pdf-reader

I am starting developing my own application pdf reader with dictionary support but I can't find useful way to integrate offline dictionary with pdf reader.

Comment: Add more details about your project and the offline dictionary you are trying to integrate.

Comment: What is the goal of your app? To translate the pdf? As @vaibhav says, give us more info.

Comment: @Milos & @ vaibhav i want to show meaning of word when user click on particular word in 1 window.any offline dictionary present in mobile

Comment: That seems to be a dificult task. Android does not have a built in pdf reader. As on computers, you will have to use an existing pdf reader, which cannot be changed. So, to acheave your goal, you will have to write your own pdf reader (or modifie an open source one) and then use an offline dictionary with. I think you shouldn't start doing this.

Comment: thanks @milos actually i already start working on this project i m recently study open source pdf reader source we have any idea to simplify this work ,i thinking about copy selected word and show its result in present offline dictionary in mobile with start as new activity

Comment: Ah, ok, so you have already a working pdf reader. In this case, you can implement (override) onClick() function to trigger an action when a word is clicked. So, when you clicks a word, the onClick action will be trigered and you should cacthc the clicked word. Then, you will have to search for this word in your database (offline dictionary) and return in a view or a popup the obtainted result.

Answer (score -1):

From what we discussed in comments, here is a posssibely solution:

The most difficult should be the pdf reader implementation. As you told me, you have found an open access pdf reader for android, so it is fine.

In order to implement an offline dictionary with your existing pdf reader, I suggest you this:

**1.** 
Modifie your pdf reader to catch a word click (or long click). You have to be carreful with that because I don't know how you implemented the pdf scroll. So the system hould be able to distinguish if the user is trying to scroll, zoom the pdf, or to click a word in order to see the definition.

**2.**
Once you can catch the word click, you wil have to use the clicked word and search in your offline dictionary. for that, create a SQLite database: see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html and search for the clicked word.

**3.**
Once the results obtained, you can display your result in a dialog or another view, or even in your pdf reader if you implement this function.